# AE2 Inscriber auto crafting is not importing the final product into the computer

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-feed-the-beast

So I'm playing sky factory from the ATLauncher and managed to make an auto crafting system from the Applied Energetics 2 mod. I followed this [set up](https://imgur.com/a/2o8PC) to automate my inscribers and it works great but the problem is that once the processor has finished crafting it stays in the inscriber and doesn't get imported into the computer. Here is a picture of my setup:
[image: My Setup]

**NOTE**: I used the feed the beast tag because I followed the feed the beast wiki to find this. Also, I downloaded the world that is downloadable from the link I sent and it works perfectly fine!

**EDIT**: I tried to add an import bus into the inscriber but nothing happened. In the set up I followed, there were no import buses used (And also I think this set up was created by a developer of the mod) and it still somehow imports them into the computer.

Comment: Can't see the back but those look like two export buses - you need an import bus to get the item out of the inscriber

Comment: @JonK I already tried to add an import bus but nothing happened. If you check out the link, you'll actually see that no import buses were used. Weird but in the world I downloaded it works somehow. I just can't quite figure out why... Edited the question to add that info

Comment: I've followed that tutorial myself - there should be an ME Import Bus going into the ME Interface (at the back) on the right side of your picture. It's a little hard to tell, but I can't see any cable going behind your ME Interface. Would it be possible to provide a screenshot of the back side of the setup?

Comment: @JonK Not trying to sound like a butt, but there is no mention of an import bus in the tutorial. And I figured out what the problem was, I forgot to put the finished product in the export bus filter in the export bus facing the back of the interface. (Idk how it works but somehow it puts the processors into the computer)

Comment: The final step mentions it but if you've sorted it out then it's academic anyway